# Как в Java считать определенное количество байт из файла по URL?

Tags: java, android

**Java** код:

```
URL urlw = new URL("http://95.161.19.3:8000/low");
HttpURLConnection Connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlw.openConnection();
recordingStream = Connection.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer= new byte[1];
while (true){
        if (recordingStream.read(buffero, 0, 1) != -1 && isFlg) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, 1); // запись в файл.
                writer.flush();
        }
}
```

Читает в цикле поток по одному(!) байту и пишет этот байт в бинарный файл.
Видимо это разрабатывалось во времена GPRS.
Увеличение буфера приводит к потере байтов. Файл не читаем.

**Python** код:

```
bp = urllib.urlopen("http://95.161.19.3:8000/low")
while True:
      dpa=bp.read(1024) // да хоть 1000000, и без потерь.
      writer.write(dpa)
```

Вопрос,  можно так же в **Java**?

Comment: [не подойдет](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295221/java-net-url-read-stream-to-byte)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] buffer= new byte[1024];
while (true){
        int lenght = recordingStream.read(buffero);

        if (lenght != -1 && isFlg) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, lenght); // запись в файл.
                writer.flush();
        } else 
             break;
}
```

Comment: Есть вариант сразу по 80 кб читать за оборот, - потеря байтов, файл заполняется чёрти чем. Ну можно и так. Но а если нужно считать ровно 16000 байт?